Folder structure in Next.js project, having reusable SWR hooks
I am trying to add SWR to my Next.js project but having trouble figuring out where to put my reusable SWR hooks.
For example, I have this useUser hook I call in multiple components:
export default function useUser() {
    return useSWR('/api/user');
}

My question is, where should I put this useUser.ts file?
From what I've seen people tend to put their SWR files in a hooks folder.
I want to know if there are any alternatives since I think it could be pretty confusing to have API calls and normal hooks (like useDebounce) inside a hooks folder.
